# Suspend failure after 17,04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, power-management, 17.04

I have a desktop computer with:

- Intel Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00GHz × 2
- GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2 graphics.

Until recently it was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 16.10 in dual boot.  Both versions would suspend and awaken correctly.  About a month ago I upgraded the 16.10 installation to 17.04.  At about the same time, there was a large update to 16.04.  Since then neither version will suspend and awaken.  On the sleep button or suspend from the menu or suspend from the power settings, the machine shuts down completely and will only restart from cold with the power button.  There are no errors reported in the pm-suspend log.  I have Nvidia driver 381.22 and the update to 17.04 from last Friday installed.  Can anyone help to resolve this.  There have been no hardware or BIOS changes.

I have tried 375 and 378 as well as 381.09, all with the same result.  The problem occurs on suspend, not on wake up.  The power light on the box goes off after suspend.  It used to flash slowly while suspended.

After today's updates, with kernels 4.4.0-78 and 4.10.0-21, neither version will suspend correctly.  16.04 is using driver 375 and 17.04 is using driver 381.

Comment: Have you checked the kernel version as suggested? Are you, in fact, running kernel 4.10?

Answer (score 0):

Check `$ uname -a`

It is possible that the upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 did not properly load the 4.10.x kernel. There is a scripting error that prevents the 4.10.x kernel from installing properly. If your uname -a shows the old 4.8.x kernel version. Then this is the case for you. The new code is not designed to work with the older kernel. And, among others, power management is a problem.

This issue is discussed on launchpad... [HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1681566)

Installing a newer kernel is not very easy. But, one way is to add the PPA for the lastest kernels into your Software Update ---> Other Software. I believe the PPA address is `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/` [Sorry that doesn't seem to be the correct listing - Can anyone add that here?]
After you add the PPA and exit Software Updates, the cache will rebuild. Then open software updater and the 4.10.x kernel should be among the updates listed.

If that doesn't work for you. Please search "install newer kernel". And, you will find much info on that.

OR you can trust this little tutorial and just do it manually. I am assuming a 64bit system here. If you are using a 32bit system, the "_amd64.deb" part of the filenames below should be changed to "_i386.deb"

First:

```
$ cd /tmp
```

Second enter:

```
$ wget \  <ENTER>   
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10/linux-headers-4.10.0-041000_4.10.0-041000.201702191831_all.deb \
    kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10/linux-headers-4.10.0-041000-generic_4.10.0-041000.201702191831_amd64.deb \
    kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10/linux-image-4.10.0-041000-generic_4.10.0-041000.201702191831_amd64.deb
```

Hit  after each line and when ALL of them are completed, wait for the download to complete and return you to your host prompt. Don't change directory. Stay where you are. And...

Then enter:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.10*.deb linux-image-4.10*.deb
```

Once finished, reboot. The new kernel should be confirmed by issuing

```
$ uname -a
```

You are now running the correct kernel for Ubuntu 17.04 :-D

---- Also. May I suggest ----

I found the above when I was looking for a solution to a "return from suspend' problem involving nVidia driver problems. I was also using 381.22 So, I also recommend that you consider dropping down to the 375.x version of Nvidia drivers listed in "Additional Drivers". 381.x is problematic when returning from suspend on some chipsets.

There is also a confirmed bug with nVidia when using the updater to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 that relates to nVidia adapters and prevents video from recovering from suspend mode when using the newer 381.22 driver. the explanation is at the same link as above.

To downgrade nVidia driver to 375.x;

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-375
```

Then select the 375.xx driver from "Additional Drivers" in "Software Updates". They "might" not appear in the list until you reboot.

I hope this helps with your problem.